# CURL POST не работает

Tags: php, curl

Здраствуйте. Хочу с помощью курла отправить пост запрос чтобы перейти по ссылке(внешне ссылка выглядит так

```
<a id="ctl00_plhMain_lnkSchApp" class="purplelink" href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$plhMain$lnkSchApp','')">Далее</a>
```

Передаю пост - запрос :

```
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1); 
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,'некий пост-текст').
```

Все данные запроса который отправляется взят из firebug, там четко указано что это пост метод. Но в результате сервер возвращает

> HTTP/1.1 405 Method Not Allowed
>   Allow: OPTIONS, TRACE, GET, HEAD
>   Content-Length: 1564 Content-Type: text/html
>   Server: Microsoft-IIS/6.0 
>   X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
>   Date: Thu, 01 Sep 2016 16:45:55 GMT

то есть метод POST не разрешен. Не могу понять,в чем проблема: или я не правильно задаю запрос, или действительно здесь не метод пост нужен,может есть другой способ перейти по ссылке?

Comment: Код ответа 405 значит, что на данный URL нельзя отправить запрос с используемым вами методом. Более того, заголовок `Allow` явно говорит, что ожидаются только запросы с методами  `OPTIONS`, `TRACE`, `GET`, `HEAD`.

Comment: Я понимаю,но firebug указывает что при переходе по данной ссылке передавались данные пост методом. Выходит он врет?

Answer (score 1):

Полагаю, вам следует передавать правильный Content-Type и корректный CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS